# Form pandas series of elements by taking dictionary as a input wherein value indicates frequency of key in that dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, sklearn-pandas

I have a dictionary object,

```
z = {"a":3, "b":2, "c":5}
```

Based on that,

I desire to get output object as pandas series or array as,

```
array(["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"])
```

Even if elements in output series are not in order that is fine, but should reflect same count as of value for its respective key element in input dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `np.repeat`

```
import numpy as np

np.repeat(*zip(*z.items()))
#array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one solution :

```
z = {"a":3, "b":2, "c":5}
list=[]
for i in z: list += [i]*z[i]

print(list)

['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```